# cropit jQuery plugin - How to set up a custom drop zone?

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, cropit

I'm using [cropit](https://github.com/scottcheng/cropit) - a "customizable crop and zoom" jQuery plugin.

The following code is the HTML structure used by cropit. And by default, users can drag and drop images onto `.cropit-preview-image-container`. My question is that how can I set up a custom drop zone? Since I want a drop zone larger than the image size.

```
.cropit-preview
  .cropit-preview-background-container
    img.cropit-preview-background
  .cropit-preview-image-container
    img.cropit-preview-image
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out how to do it.

```
var cropit = $('.image-editor').data('cropit');

$('.dropzone').on('dragover dragleave', cropit.onDragOver.bind(cropit));
$('.dropzone').on('drop', cropit.onDrop.bind(cropit));
```

In this way, when you drop an image on `.dropzone`, the image will replace `img.cropit-preview-image`.

Comment: This saved me creating a massive js function, thanks.